# Accessing Application_PostAuthorizeRequest via pipeline

Tags: pipelines

I'm working on a scenario that requires I use session state in API calls. I found an article that discusses the setup, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-handle-session-in-web-api/, but it requires hooking into the `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` function of `global.asax`. I'd rather not have a `global.asax` modification, and I know it's common to have `Application_Start` content called using the `Initialize` pipeline. Does anyone know of a similar pipeline for `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest`?

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are using?

Comment: Using Sitecore 9.0.2. Modifying the global.asax does work, I'd like to find a cleaner/"Sitecorian" way if possible.

Comment: Sitecore9 httpRequestBegin pipeline fires from OnPostAuthentication HTTP module event. This was previously from OnBegin event, so you should be able to access authenticated user information in the pipeline now.

Comment: Looks like that should do the trick, if you'd like to classify that as an answer, I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Sitecore 9**, the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline fires from `OnPostAuthentication` HTTP module event. This was previously from the `OnBegin` event, so you should be able to access authenticated user information in the pipeline now.

Please keep in mind this will fire for each request.

**sample code here:**

```
public class PostAuthentication : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {           
            // Here you can write yours post auth logic

            //check authenticat user i.e. Context.User.IsAuthenticated
        }
    }
```

You can add config patch as per your requirement:

```
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>      
      <httpRequestBegin>
        <processor type="xxx.xxx.xxx.Pipelines.PostAuthentication, assemblyName"  patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

I am not sure if you can access the session. Alternatively you can use custom properties(user profile), e.g. `Context.User.Profile.SetCustomProperty("User ID","testuser")`.